# How to change the performance index of the hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, performance-tuning

I would like to know how to change the performance index of the hard disk 
 and why it remains at 5.9.

Answer (score 10):

The performance index of the disk is based on its mechanical (eg: rotation speed) and electronic design (eg: cache size) and although you may be able to make some minor adjustments to its operating parameters using manufacturer-supplied tools (if available), you're stuck with what you have and the only way to improve your disk performance index would be to obtain a higher-spec disk.

Edit: Just discovered that the highest possible rating for a mechanical disk under Windows 7 is 5.9 anyway - 6 and above are reserved for SSDs:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/increasing-windows-experience-rating-for-hard/6379c463-715f-4a2e-9f4c-2943ab94e1e9

Comment: +1 Good Link, but if you read the link it links to it doesn't specifically check for SSDs, just for a high Random I/O rate (which will usually mean SSD).

Answer (score 2):

- Faster Interface
- Faster Hard Drive
- Faster Motherboard
- Faster Bios